# How to capture Ctrl-Z keystroke in a RichTextBox

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I need to capture when the user presses `CTRL-Z` (press `CTRL` and `Z` at the same time) in a RichTextBox control.

I've turned off the `ShortCutsEnabled` property.  I've tried every combination I can think of using `KeyCode` and `KeyData` with the `KeyDown` and `KeyPress` events.

I can capture EITHER a `CTRL` OR a `Z`, but never both together.  Is `RichTextBox` capturing this keystroke before I can see it, even if shortcuts are disabled?

Does anyone have a solution that works for this?

Answer (score 4):

you could simply use CTRL-Z

```
 textBox1.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(textBox1_KeyDown);

void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
         if(e.KeyCode == Keys.Z && (e.Control)) {
             MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + Z Pressed!");
         }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked!  I also learned that I need to leave ShortCutsEnabled turned ON.

Answer (score 1):

Check `KeyCode` and `Modifiers` in the `KeyDown` event:

```
private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Modifiers == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
        MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-Z Pressed");
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this worked, too!  I also learned that I need to leave ShortCutsEnabled turned ON.

Answer (score 0):

```
  void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
  {
      if ((Control.ModifierKeys & Keys.Control) == Keys.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.Z)
        {
             MessageBox.Show("Ctrl + Z is Pressed");
        }
  }
```

try this.